# Can anybody provide me Ibn Taymiyyah's book al-Aqidah al-Waasitiyyah as PDF, please?

Tags: sharia, islamic-scholar, books, aqidah

When I've come acrossed the famous book of Shaykh al-Islām Ibn Taymiyyah  which is ***Al-Aqidah al-Waasitiyyah*** (The Creed to the People of Wāsiṭ), it become a dream of mine that at any cost I need to read this book. But till now I couldn’t manage to read it. So I request you, anyone, who have it as full English translated PDF, just give a chance to read it. I badly want to read this amazing book. So, can anybody help me out?

Comment: These kinds of questions are not on-topic. We are not a typical internet forum.

Comment: Aqee**q**ah and Aqee**d**ah are different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Asalaam alaikum**

The book is widely available on .pdf format and since you requested for it here is a link you can download it from, in Sha Allah.

https://darpdfs.org/aqeedah-manhaj/

https://archive.org/search.php?query=Al%20AQIDAH%20AL%20WASITIYYAH

Above are a couple of working links where you can find AL AQIDAH AL WASITIYYAH.pdf in English

**NOTE** i recommend reading *commentry on Al AQIDAH AL WASITIYYAH by sheikh uthaymeen which comes in 2 volumes. It will provide a more laymen's understanding as well*

May Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

**Allah knows best**